# Why gcc gives to me warnings?

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

Why when I compile with gcc I get some warnings about the compiled code?

I have tried to change some parts of the code to suppress the warnings, but when I get suppress the warnings when compile then when it is runing there are errors and the debug session stop.

Any help to understand why is happening this would be welcome.

The warnings I get are the followings:

```
gcc Question_1.c -o Question_1
Question_1.c: In function ‘main’:
Question_1.c:43:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘menu’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 menu(&name_file_in,&name_file_out);
      ^
Question_1.c:5:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[17]’
void menu(char *name_file_in,char *name_file_out)
  ^~~~
Question_1.c:43:24: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘menu’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 menu(&name_file_in,&name_file_out);
                    ^
Question_1.c:5:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[16]’
void menu(char *name_file_in,char *name_file_out)
  ^~~~
```

The C code that produce it is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void menu(char *name_file_in,char *name_file_out)
{

int option;

do
{
    printf("\n1. To write a name for an input file.");
    printf("\n2. To write a name for an output file.");
    printf("\n3. Exit.");
    printf("\n\nWrite an option (1-3): ");
    scanf("%d",&option);

    switch(option)
    {
        case 1: printf("\nWrite a name for the input file, (1 default): ");
                scanf("%s",&*name_file_in);
                if(strcmp(&*name_file_in,"1")==0)
                    strcpy(&*name_file_in,"data_in.dat");
                printf("\nThe input filename is: %s\n",&*name_file_in);
                break;

        case 2: printf("\nWrite a name for the output file, (1 default): ");
                scanf("%s",&*name_file_out);
                if(strcmp(&*name_file_out,"1")==0)
                    strcpy(&*name_file_out,"data_out.dat");
                printf("\nThe output filename is: %s\n",&*name_file_out);
                break;

     }

} while(option!=3);

}

int main()
{
    char name_file_in[17],name_file_out[16];
    menu(&name_file_in,&name_file_out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: `&*ptr` is weird way of writing `ptr` :)

Comment: The compiler error is painfully clear. The compiler is even pointing out the bug for you with a little `^` arrow saying "bug here". How much clearer do you need it to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
menu(&name_file_in,&name_file_out);
```

When you use `&` you are trying to pass address of complete array which is  `char (*)[17]`

Pass the address of first element in the array as below.

```
  menu(name_file_in, name_file_out);
```

Or

Expect the array with fixed size at the function as below.

```
void menu(char (*name_file_in)[17], char (*name_file_out)[16])
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kiran Biradar. You are great!. :)

Comment: @DavidGómezCorrales Anytime :)